# Delete row from UITableView when I have multiple sections iOS (values are in Dynamic NSMutableDictionary)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

Let me describe my scenario first.

I have a `NSMutableDictionary` called `self.wordDic`, which basically have some `key` & `value` like this: (This dictionary is dynamic, not fixed)

```
key     value
---------------------------------------------------------
A       (Apple, Aim, Arise, Attempt, Airplane, Absolute)
B       (Bubble, Bite, Borrow, Basket)
C       (Cat, Correct)
D       (Dog, Direction, Distribute)
```

Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([self.wordListArray count] != 0)
    {
        self.wordDic = [self sortedDictionary:self.wordInWordListArray];

        // Sorted key array
        self.keyArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        NSArray *key = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        key = [self.wordDic allKeys];
        self.keyArray = [key sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    }
}
```

I have an `NSArray` called `keyArray` where I have all of my `NSDictionary` keys **(Alphabetically)**. And then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I show all my values of a particular `key` **(Alphabetically)**.

Please take have a look into my `tableView` methods :

My `tableView`:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.keyArray count];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 28;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 28)];
    // Add title label
    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 100, 18)];
    [titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0f]];
    NSString *string = [self.keyArray objectAtIndex:section];

    [titleLabel setText:string];
    [view addSubview:titleLabel];

    return view;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return kHomeTableViewCellHeight;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *key = [self.keyArray objectAtIndex:section];
    NSMutableArray *value = [self.wordDic objectForKey:key];

    return [value count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = kHomeTableViewCellID;
    HomeTableViewCell *cell = (HomeTableViewCell *)[self.homeTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[HomeTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    NSString *secTitle = [self.keyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    secData = [self.wordDic objectForKey:secTitle];
    [secData sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSString *data = [secData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.wordLabel setText:data];

    return cell;
}
```

Everything works perfectly. But now I want to delete my rows.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Other code
    ..............
    ..............


    // remove info from tableView array
    [self.whichArraywillBeHere removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.myTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

In `commitEditingStyle` with which array I should have to replace this **self.whichArraywillBeHere** array? Cause, first I have no section in this method and secondly, I load my rows, alphabetically. SO how can I know which array, should I used here and what will be it's `indexPath`??
If you understand my problem please reply.

Thanks a lot in advance.
Have a good day. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you're very close - you already have your keyArray sorted and stored in a property.  You can get the values array from the dictionary with this - just like you did in the data source methods.  The quick and dirty way to delete the right row/word would be to just sort it again.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  // Other code
  // ..
  // remove info from tableView array

  NSString *key = [self.keyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
  NSMutableArray *words = [self.wordDic objectForKey:key];
  [words sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

  [words removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  [self.myTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Again this is the quick solution, note that you sort the array(s) each time a row is deleted and also anytime the table is reloaded (but if your word arrays are small this may not matter - that's up to you)

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why this simple thing didn't come to my head last night.